# Cannot read data - option() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sfUrl'

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to read data from snowflake database table into databricks. Below is my code:

```
options = {
 "sfUrl": "xxxxxx.snowflakecomputing.com",
 "sfUser": "xxxxxxx",
 "sfPassword": "xxxx",
 "sfDatabase": "xxxxxxx",
  "sfSchema": "xxxxxxx",
 "sfWarehouse": "xxxxxxxxx",
 "sfRole": "xxxxxxxx"
}

df = spark.read.format('snowflake').option(**options).option('query', 'select * from mytable').load()
```

I got the error like below:

```
TypeError: option() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sfUrl'
```

I followed the instruction on[this link](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/snowflake-python.html).  I do not understand why it failed.  Does anyone know what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change sfUrl to sfURL and then test this operation.